# Plone/Dexterity Container- How can I prevent a container type from being deleted if there are contents in it?

Tags: plone, dexterity

I have a container that I want to prevent from being deleted if there are contents in it.  Like if they hit delete under actions and hit confirm, a status message or an exception message (ala Insufficient Priviliges) could appear.

I thought maybe using an event subscriber like IObjectWillBeRemovedEvent and IObjectRemovedEvent and raising an exception message if there were contents in the container would work, but it went ahead and deleted the container without any error message displaying.

```
@grok.subscribe(IMyContainerType,IObjectRemovedEvent (or IObjectWillBeRemoved))
def timesheetDeletion(obj,event):
    if len(obj.getFolderContents()) > 0:
        raise LinkIntegrityNotificationException('There are contents in this container.  To maintain integrity of aggregation, please delete contents first')
```

I'm not sure if that's the right exception, but I keep on coming cross that being used in topics and questions related to preventing an object from being deleted.

I can't help but feel that there must be a simpler way to do this, perhaps without needing an event, but I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: I came up with a workaround.  I have a workflow assigned to the container with the 'Delete portal content' (collective.deletepermission) as a permission managed by the workflow.  The specific content type allowed is assigned two subscribers for adding and deleting.  When the content is added, the role responsible for deleting the container (the content type's parent) is removed from the roles of the permission on the object.  When the content is deleted and the container (the content type's parent) doesn't have any content, the role is added again to the roles of the permission.

Comment: I don't think my comment constitutes as a good answer as its more of a workaround for my specific needs.  Since my way just removes the Delete action from the actions drop down, the design could be considered inconsistent.  However, I could just leave a note on my template indicating that the container cannot be deleted if there is content in it.

Comment: Can't get why it's not working for you. I used https://github.com/redomino/redomino.protectdelete in a project and it's using the same event (try to look at the code).

Comment: You really, really do not want to subscribe to IObjectRemovedEvent; simplify and just subscribe to (first and only) IObjectWillBeRemovedEvent.  Read the OFS.ObjectManager.ObjectManager source, you will see (re: order) that this matters.

Comment: @LucaFabbri - Thanks!  I think I misunderstood what the raise error was doing.

Comment: *The raise exception I was using was doing.

@sdupton: 
Thank you for the recommendation of using WillBeRemovedEvent.  It does make more sense to use in my instance since I want to prevent the deletion from occurring, where as ObjectRemoved fires, according to Plone Documentation, after the object has been deleted.

Comment: There is ine more issue I was having.  getFolderContents was returning nothing.  Does the metadata or indexes get removed when firing this event?  listFolderContent returns the contents as objects so they're still there.

Comment: I'm somewhat doubtful that anything OOTB would remove anything catalog-related (used for navigation) in IObjectWillBeRemovedEvent, unless you have some kind of rogue subscriber, or unless the LinkIntegrityNotificationException is raised improperly (which might be the case).